# create trigger that delete and update data in other table

Tags: plsql, triggers

i have 2 tables. I need to write a trigger IN PL/SQL that any time update or delete OF PROJCODE in TABLE 1(assignment) , UPDATE CODE in project and remove code from project that it doesn't appear any more in table1. THEN PRINT OUT THE COLUM (CODE) IN PROJECT TABLE

I tried to write this code but still get error that code doesnt declare and :new.code and :old.code are bad bind variable 'OLD.CODE'!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_1
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OF PROJCODE
  ON ASSIGNMENT
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE PRODUCT P
    SET P.CODE = :new.CODE
    WHERE P.CODE = :old.CODE;
  ELSE
     DELETE FROM PROJECT WHERE :old.CODE= CODE ;
  END IF;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CODE);
END;
```

How can I solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger should become:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_1
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON PROJCODE
  REFERENCING new AS new old AS old
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE PRODUCT P
    SET P.CODE = :new.CODE
    WHERE P.CODE = :old.CODE;
  ELSE
     DELETE FROM PROJECT WHERE :old.CODE= CODE ;
  END IF;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CODE);
END;
/
```

Comment: The trigger doesn't fire for `INSERT`s, so if it enters the `ELSE` block, it has been fired for a `DELETE` operation.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_1
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OF PROJCODE
  ON ASSIGNMENT
  FOR EACH ROW
  REFERENCING  new AS new old AS old
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
          UPDATE PRODUCT 
          SET CODE = :new.code
          WHERE CODE = :old.code;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( CODE );
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
           DELETE FROM PROJECT WHERE :old.code = CODE ;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( CODE );
   END IF;
END;

i got this error :s
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

Comment: Also, it should be `BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON PROJCODE`, not `BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OF PROJCODE`. You should use `ON` instead of `OF`

Comment: @Luke, yes, I didn't notice the triggering event statement. But apart from this, there are a few other mistakes in the code that I have tried to rectify. Thanks for pointing it out!